# Saving private lobby replays in Dota 2

Tags: dota-2

Before the latest patch, I would play custom lobby games with bots and cheats enabled in order to do something specific, finish the match quickly and be able to analyze the replay afterwards. Basically I would do what I needed to do, buy 6 rapiers, and finish the game to get the replay. The game would always automatically save it to the "replays" folder as "auto-[match id]-[some random number]-[my account name].dem", so I didn't have to do anything to retrieve it. But since the latest patch, none of my replays are saved automatically, and when I try to download them using the match id, I would always get "Replay Unavailable" when I click the "Download Replay" button. So there's no way I can get them back.

Could there have been an option that was reset in the new patch, or did Valve completely remove this feature? I can't find any information on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have to download manually.
Becuase of this is a private match you can not see in the history but you can see it in the last match at the menu top right corner, you can click it, and download it!
Then everything will be the same as the old patch :)

Comment: That's what I tried, but when I click Download, I get "Replay Unavailable". Before, all of my private lobby games would automatically save to the replays folder, without having to do anything. But now, even the game client won't let me download my replay from my last matches section :/